# Update apk file on Google Play

Tags: android, python-2.7, sqlite, apk, kivy

I want to publish an Android application that I have developed but have a minor concern.

The application will load with a **database file (or sqlite3 file)**. If updates arise in the future and these updates are only targeting the application's **functionality** without the **database structure**, I wish to allow users to keep their saved entries in their sqlite3 files.

So what is the best practice to send updates? Compile the apk files with the new updated code only and without the database files? Or is there any other suggestion?

*PS: I am not working with Java and Eclipse, but with python for Android and the Kivy platform which is an amazing new way for developing Android applications.*

Comment: Thanks I never knew we could develop for Android with Python. Next Target Python!

Comment: yes you can and it is with Kivy. Check the Kivy project.Still under development but is giving me nice results

Answer (score 0):

if you're using local sqlite then you have to embed the database file within the app as failure to do so it means there's no database, in case for updates database have version numbers where as it can not upgrade the database provided the version number is the same as the previous app updates

Comment: not so sure i got you. or i might not have asked the question properly. the database file is not some kind of parametric table or so but it is for the application users to add, edit and delete their input. All i want is to preserve their inputs if they update. i need a simple way to do so.

Comment: okay i misunderstood you here is the post that will take you through what you're looking for http://www.sitepoint.com/using-database-in-android/

Comment: Thanks a lot i shall take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I started my app but since **kivy** has no solution for this I tried to create a directory outside my app directory in android with a simple `os.mkdir('../##')` and I put all the files there. Hope this helps!